# How to design a custom cmake FindOOXX module with versioning like FindQt4?

Tags: cmake, maya

I would like to design a cmake FindOOXX module for Autodesk Maya with support of versioning, just like what FindQt4.cmake provides. ex,

```
find_package(Qt4 4.4.3)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Does anyone has a simple but complete cmake module sample like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CMake modules directory there is a file `readme.txt` which contains useful information for CMake module writers. This is the relevant section from that file on how version numbers are passed to the module:

```
If any version numbers are given to the command it will set the
following variables before loading the module:

  XXX_FIND_VERSION       = full requested version string
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR = major version if requested, else 0
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_MINOR = minor version if requested, else 0
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_PATCH = patch version if requested, else 0
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_TWEAK = tweak version if requested, else 0
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_COUNT = number of version components, 0 to 4
  XXX_FIND_VERSION_EXACT = true if EXACT option was given
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps to get this variable references.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Qt4 find script in your CMake install folder under share\cmake-2.8\Modules.

Comment: I did but it's too complicated to me ;p